# Problem for authenticating login creds in Flask

Tags: sql, session, flask, flask-login

I'm trying to authenticate a login request from my login.html file

```
        <form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="post">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2>Already a user, Login here!</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="username" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password" required>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
                </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

here is the flask snippet

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():

    username = request.form.get("username")
    password = request.form.get("password")
    if db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password", {"username": username, "password": password}).fetchone() == username:
        session['username'] = username
        return render_template("home.html")

    return render_template("error.html", message="username or password is incorrect",prompt="alert alert-warning")
```

When I enter wrong creds, it prompts me to the wrong creds message, which I pretty much want. Now problem is if I add the correct creds, then also it is showing me the same message. My database is connected properly and there's no issue with that. Is something wrong with my way of writing the query, as I'm a beginner in Flask and SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchone` returns a sequence (list), so the `if` test is never true.

From the [python Sqlite3 doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone):

> **fetchone()**
>
> Fetches the next row of a query result set, returning a single sequence, or None when no more data is available.

One option: Since the result of `fetchone` is a list, the element to compare with username would be the first member returned i.e. `....fetchone()[0]`.

Another option: Assuming `username` is unique, the query will return one row or no rows. `fetchone` will return `None` if there are no rows. `None` is falsey therefore the equality is not necessary in the `if` clause.

Comment: Ok, what should I do in order to serve the purpose of matching it with the entered credentials?

Comment: some solution options added to answer